# Unable to access another server over local network on Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mysql, firewall

I have two servers. Let's call them A and B. Both are running ubuntu server 14.04. B runs percona server. Now I do not have any firewall set-up on either servers still I am unable to connect to server B from A. Percona server is bound to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

When I do a

```
 telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 3306

      - where the IP is a local private IP
```

from A, I am unable to access it. Whereas, the server B also runs a SSH and when I try to do:

```
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 22
```

I am able to connect. Can some tell me why is this happening?

Comment: What is output of `cat /etc/xinetd.d/telnet` in both servers. Paste the output of both systems in your question

Comment: On Server A I get
$ cat /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
cat: /etc/xinetd.d/telnet: No such file or directory

On Server B I get

cat /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
cat: /etc/xinetd.d/telnet: No such file or directory

Comment: Percona server is a replacement server for mysql or mariadb, it is not like SSH. See this for more info https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-fresh-percona-server-or-replace-mysql

Comment: Yes I know that. And that is why I am using it. I have other servers as well from which I am able to access server B and also am able to do a telnet <local-IP> 3306 from those servers

Comment: Have you removed mysql before installing percona? and have you restarted mysql service before using percona

Comment: I did not have mysql installed. And, as I told you I am able to access the same mysql instance using other servers that I have. Also, I just tried this:

     traceroute -T -p 3306 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

and it just prints:

    1 * * *

But when I do

    traceroute -T -p 22 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

I get the reply in the first hop

Answer (score 0):

I checked. The issue was with thr firewall. Iptables was not registered as a service. So issuing a firewall command to allow from my ip worked. Command used was:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```